# How to get a name of a variable coming into a function as a parameter using F#?

Tags: function, f#, parameters, quotations

Is there any way in F# how to get a name of a variable passed into a function?

Example:

```
let velocity = 5
let fn v = v.ParentName
let name = fn velocity // this would return "velocity" as a string
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Why this code does not work? It is matched as value, so I can not retrieve the "variable" name.

```
type Test() =
  let getName (e:Quotations.Expr) =
    match e with
      | Quotations.Patterns.PropertyGet (_, pi, _) -> pi.Name + " property"
      | Quotations.Patterns.Value(a) -> failwith "Value matched"
      | _ -> failwith "other matched"
  member x.plot v = v |> getName |> printfn "%s"

let o = new Test()

let display () =
  let variable = 5.
  o.plot <@ variable @>

let runTheCode fn = fn()

runTheCode display
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For completing Marcelo's answer, yes you can use quotations for this task:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let velocity = 5

let fn (e:Expr) =
  match e with
    | PropertyGet (e, pi, li) -> pi.Name
    | _ -> failwith "not a let-bound value"

let name = fn <@velocity@> 

printfn "%s" name
```

As you can see in the code, F# let-bound top definition values (functions or variables) are implemented as properties of a class.

I can't find anymore the link that shows how a piece of F# code could be rewritten in a functional way with C#. Seeing the code, it becomes obvious why you need a `PropertyGet` pattern.

Now if you want to evaluate the expression too, you will need to install [F# powerpack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/40168) and reference `FSharp.PowerPack.Linq` in your project.

It adds an `EvalUntyped` method on `Expr` class..

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

let velocity = 5

let fn (e:Expr) =
  match e with
    | PropertyGet (eo, pi, li) -> pi.Name, e.EvalUntyped
    | _ -> failwith "not a let-bound value"

let name, value = fn <@velocity@> 

printfn "%s %A" name value
```

If you need to do it for the method of an instance, here's how I would do it:

```
let velocity = 5

type Foo () =
  member this.Bar (x:int) (y:single) = x * x + int y

let extractCallExprBody expr =
  let rec aux (l, uexpr) =
    match uexpr with
     | Lambda (var, body) -> aux (var::l, body)
     | _ -> uexpr
  aux ([], expr)

let rec fn (e:Expr) =
  match e with
    | PropertyGet (e, pi, li) -> pi.Name
    | Call (e, mi, li) -> mi.Name
    | x -> extractCallExprBody x |> fn
    | _ -> failwith "not a valid pattern"

let name = fn <@velocity@> 
printfn "%s" name

let foo = new Foo()

let methodName = fn <@foo.Bar@>
printfn "%s" methodName
```

Just to come back on the code snippet showing usage of `EvalUntyped`, you can add an explicit type parameter for `Expr` and a downcast (`:?>`) if you want/need to keep things type-safe:

```
let fn (e:Expr<'T>) = 
  match e with
    | PropertyGet (eo, pi, li) -> pi.Name, (e.EvalUntyped() :?> 'T)
    | _ -> failwith "not a let-bound value"
    
let name, value = fn <@velocity@> //value has type int here
printfn "%s %d" name value
```

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot! One additional question. How do I get a value out of the expression?

Comment: Thanks! And a final question :) If the fn is a member of a type (member this.fn = ...), how do I do it?

Comment: Just to be curious, why do you need to retrieve the name of a value/member?

Comment: Well, I have created a type Matlab which communicates with Matlab :). And if you want to plot a variable, you call "member this.plot variables" and then I need to retrieve names of the variables and send them to Matlab. So I need to retrieve names of parameters of the member functions like plot etc.

Comment: Hi,
I have modified my first post, could you please take a look at it? Is it the correct way, how to post additional questions?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I don't think this is doable. You can get the name of a value using quotations but only for top-level definition values. So you will have to take "let variable = 5." out of the display function and put it at the top-level.

Yes, if you have additional questions you will have to edit your Q. You did right. But don't hesitate to ask a fresh new question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve this with code quotations:

```
let name = fn <@ velocity @>
```

The `fn` function will be passed an `Expr` object, which it must cast to `Quotations.Var` (which it will only be if you pass a single variable) and extract the `Name` instance member.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How do I cast it?
this:
let velExpr = <@ velocity @>
let casted = velExpr :?> Quotations.Var
does not work

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous solutions I came out with a more generic solution where you can get the name of functions, lambdas, values, properties, methods, static methods, public fields, Union types:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let cout (s:string)= System.Console.WriteLine (s)

let rec getName exprs =
    let fixDeclaringType (dt:string) =
        match dt with
        | fsi  when fsi.StartsWith("FSI_") -> "Fsi"
        | _ -> dt
    let toStr (xDeclType: System.Type) x = sprintf "%s.%s" (fixDeclaringType xDeclType.Name)  x
    match exprs with
    | Patterns.Call(_, mi, _) -> 
        toStr mi.DeclaringType mi.Name
    | Patterns.Lambda(_, expr) -> 
        getName expr
    | Patterns.PropertyGet (e, pi, li) ->  
        toStr pi.DeclaringType pi.Name
    | Patterns.FieldGet (_, fi) -> 
        toStr fi.DeclaringType fi.Name
    | Patterns.NewUnionCase(uci, _) -> 
        toStr uci.DeclaringType uci.Name
    | expresion -> "unknown_name"


let value = ""
let funcky a = a
let lambdy = fun(x) -> x*2
type WithStatic = 
    | A | B
    with static member StaticMethod a = a
let someIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.132.0.48")


getName <@ value @> |> cout
getName <@ funcky @> |> cout
getName <@ lambdy @> |> cout
getName <@ WithStatic.A @> |> cout
getName <@ WithStatic.StaticMethod @> |> cout
getName <@ someIP.MapToIPv4 @> |> cout  
getName <@ System.Net.IPAddress.Parse @> |> cout  
getName <@ System.Net.IPAddress.Broadcast @> |> cout
```